# iptables not working with "x-forwarded-for" (behind Cloudflare)

Tags: ubuntu, networking, iptables, http-headers, cloudflare

I have a webserver (Ubuntu with Apache) running behind Cloudflare. I want to block a user using the iptables. Here I want to implement the string match extension of iptables and drop the connection if **x-forwarded-for** matched. I am adding the rule with following command:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m string --string "x-forwarded-for: 216.244.66.205" --algo bm --to 65535 -j DROP
```

After adding this rule the client is still able to hit the server.

I know about Cloudflare's specific header for client IP that is **cf-connecting-ip**. If I add a rule with the following command it works as expected. Here is the rule which works fine:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m string --string "cf-connecting-ip: 216.244.66.205" --algo bm --to 65535 -j DROP
```

**Why I want to use XFF instead of **cf-connecting-ip**:**

I have a separate load-balancer (haproxy) and some of the domains are running through this instead of Cloudflare. That is why I want to use XFF because **cf-connecting-ip** is specific to Cloudflare and XFF is supported by both.

The traffic from Cloudflare to the Web server is HTTP (port 80) so http data is visible to the iptables.

I can see Cloudflare is properly attaching both **cf-connecting-ip** and XFF headers. Here is the output of tcpdump among multiple requests:

```
tcpdump -A -s 65535 'tcp port 80' | grep 216.244.66.205
```

> ```
> x-forwarded-for: 216.244.66.205
> cf-connecting-ip: 216.244.66.205
> x-forwarded-for: 216.244.66.205
> cf-connecting-ip: 216.244.66.205
> x-forwarded-for: 216.244.66.205
> cf-connecting-ip: 216.244.66.205
> x-forwarded-for: 216.244.66.205
> cf-connecting-ip: 216.244.66.205
> ```

Somehow the iptables are able to detect the **cf-connecting-ip** but not **x-forwarded-for**.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: This looks related - https://serverfault.com/a/980916/802321

Comment: @Alex this is not related. I am using the string-match extension instead of blocking the connecting IP. I know the connecting IP belongs to Cloudflare, that's why I am trying with XFF.

Answer (score 1):

The string match operates on the payload of single IP packet.

Therefore one possible reason is that the location of `x-forwarded-for:` header happens to be on a boundary of two TCP segments. Therefore first IP packet might contain `x-forw` and second IP packet `arded-for:`. Then the `string` match module doesn't match either packet.

To check if this is the reason, look into the different IP packet payloads belonging to the connection and see how the TCP segment is split into IP packets.

It is best to implement block features like this on HTTP level.

Comment: How to look into packet payloads? Is it possible with tcpdump?

Comment: You can use tcpdump or Wireshark to inspect payloads. I don't have exact instructions to tell you how to do it though.